# change a directive not to use jquery api

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found a beautiful directive by [Tosh](http://plnkr.co/edit/xLM9VX) which does almost what I want. I don't wat the clear functionality, but just get the details of the file opened. I am trying to convert this, which uses jQuery with angular native API. My attempt is here, but not working.

http://plnkr.co/edit/I5x3DH?p=preview

Any help appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original:

```js
app.directive('fileSelect', function() {
  var template = '<input type="file" name="files"/>';
  return function( scope, elem, attrs ) {
    var selector = $( template );
    elem.append(selector);
    selector.bind('change', function( event ) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope[ attrs.fileSelect ] = event.originalEvent.target.files;
      });
    });
    scope.$watch(attrs.fileSelect, function(file) {
      selector.val(file);
    });
  };
});
```

Removed the need for full jQuery and made use of some [Angular directive features](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) (the template and the two way scope variable binding):

```js
app.directive('fileSelect', function() {
  return {
    template:'<input type="file" name="files"/>',
    scope:{fileSelect:'='},
    link:function(scope,el,attrs){
      el.bind('change', function( event ) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.fileSelect = event.target.files;
      });
    });
    }
  }
});
```

New plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/F72iTY